# Can I restore "Copy To" and "Move To" to gthumb viewer context menu?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, gthumb

In the version of gthumb that came with 14.04, there were "Copy To" and "Move To" options in the right-click menu offered when viewing single images.

In the version that comes with 16.04 and later, they aren't there, you have to return to the directory browser to get those options.

Is there a way to return them to the viewer context menu?  I greatly dislike this change.

[image]